# how binding attribute is class type to datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a class with following pseudo-code :

```
class A { property : Color, property : Value}
```

I have another class B  with following pseudo-code :

```
Class B {int x, A a1, A a2, A a3 }
```

and, I have `ObservableCollection<B> b;`
I have to binding b to datagrid.
My problem is how to binding a1, a2, a3..?
I used `DataGridTemplateColumn` to present `Color` and Value. But, I couldn't binding a1 or a2..
how can I do that?
Thanks,

Comment: Post the relevant parts of your code, e.g. the class declarations and the DataGridTemplateColumn XAML.

Comment: simply bind b.a1.color ... etc

Comment: @jHilscher That wouldn't work unless `a1` and `Color` are declared as properties, not fields.

Comment: @Clemens yes I forgot, this is correct. so one could ether define them as properties or map them with other properties.

Answer (score 1):

ok, so I found solution.
I saw that there was no property to a1, a2, a3..

In xaml to present a1, a2... I wrote:

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="M1">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border Width="Auto" Background="{Binding a1.Color}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding a1.Value}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```